# Is there any Dynamic Binding During Deinitialization idiom

Tags: c++, dynamic-binding

Aka: Is there any "Calling Virtuals During Deinitialization" idiom

I am cleaning up some old code and need to fix cases where virtual methods are called in constructors and destructors. I don't know the code base and it is huge. Major rewrite is not an option.

The fix for constructors was simple. I moved the virtual calls to a static `Create` template and made all the constructors protected. Then all I needed to do was to compile and change all location causing errors to use the `Create` template. Minimal chance for regressions. However there is no analog to this for destructors.

How would you solve this?

Example code

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base()
    {
        DeInit();
    }
protected:
    virtual void DeInit()
    {
        std::cout << "Base" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
protected:
    virtual void DeInit() override
    {
        std::cout << "Derived" << std::endl;
        Base::DeInit();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Derived d;
}
```

This code does not call `Derived::DeInit` (only prints "Base"). I need to fix this kind of issues.

**[Working example code](http://cpp.sh/2djh)**

Comment: What problem do you need to solve? Virtual destructors already work as intended.

Comment: @KerrekSB: OP wants to avoid virtual calls in constructor/destructor as the behaviour of calling virtual method there is not the same as in other context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution inspired by MSalters second idea.

This solution only requires changes to `Base` class and to instantiation of `Derived` classes. No changes needed to any `Derived` implementation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Base
{
private:
    template <class T>
    class WithAutoDeInit : public T
    {
    public:
        virtual ~WithAutoDeInit() override
        {
            T::DeInit();
        }
    };

public:
    template <class T>
    static std::unique_ptr<typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value, WithAutoDeInit<T>>::type> Create()
    {
        return std::make_unique<WithAutoDeInit<T>>();
    }

    virtual ~Base() = default;

protected:
    virtual void DeInit()
    {
        std::cout << "Base" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
protected:
    virtual void DeInit() override
    {
        std::cout << "Derived" << std::endl;
        Base::DeInit();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Base::Create<Derived>();
}
```

[Working example code](http://cpp.sh/46h3)

This is not a robust solution. You can still make instances of `Derived` directly. And if you update all your `Derived` classes with protected constructors an unknowing developer could still create a new class forgetting to make its constructors protected. I wonder if this could be enforced by some kind of assert in a strategic location?

`static_assert(std::is_constructible<Derived>::value, "Derived class is constructable");`

Btw: I finally choose to rewite the code. It is managable I think, and the resulting code will off cause be simpler (hence better).

Answer (score 1):

```
...
virtual Base::~Base()
{
    Base::DeInit();
}
...

...
Derived::~Derived()
{
    // de-initialization code
    // do not call Derived::DeInit() here as otherwise Base::DeInit()
    // will be called two times
}
...
```

and cleanup of virtual function calls from destructors when spotting them.

Comment: If you do this, why not remove `DeInit` altogether? Which often is the correct choice, BTW.

Comment: @Msalters - it boils down to what author can and cannot touch and whether he can efficiently (=automatically) "inline" method calls done from destructors

Answer (score 1):

This is quite tricky, as destructors are called automatically on leaving scopes, whether by normal flow, `break`, `continue`, `return` or `throw`. That's also why you can't pass arguments to a destructor.

The straightforward solution is to call `Derived::DeInit` from `Derived::~Derived`. This has the additional benefit of still having `Derived` members available.

Another is to create your own smart pointer class, which calls `T::DeInit` before `T::~T`. To prevent this from being bypassed, return this smart pointer from your `Create`.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to have a virtual DeInit fun.

```
    #include <iostream>

    class Base
    {
    public:
        virtual ~Base()
        {
            DeInit(); //this calls Base version
        }
    protected:
        void DeInit()
        {
            std::cout << "Base" << std::endl;
        }
    };

    class Derived : public Base
    {

    public:
         ~Derived()
        {
            DeInit(); //this calls Derived version
        }
    protected:
        void DeInit() 
        {
        std::cout << "Derived" << std::endl;
        }
    };

    int main()
    {
        Derived d;
    }
```

Output:
Derived 
Base

is this what you wanted?

Comment: This is a good solution if you can(dare to) change Derived. If that is the case I would even kill the `DeInit` (and `Init`) methods and go proper RAII. However, if code base is huge and `Base` is a common base class, then the number of `Derived` classes may be vast. Hundreds or more maybe. Making changes to all of those without proper analysis and testing may be a bad idea.